# Rails.application.database_configuration: Could not load database configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting this error how can I create a new db and then run my scrape command.. I got a new laptop and I am trying to download my code from github

Comment: Please provide more information e.g stack trace? The OS of the system you're using to run your Rails? What code? What's inside database.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is database.yml in your .gitignore file? It is probably not stored in your Git repo, so you may need to create a new one or copy the one from your previous computer.

Comment: Yes the database.yml is in my. Gitignore

Comment: I don't have access to the old computer so how can I make a new db

Comment: I tried rake db:create db:migrate but I get the same type of error... Any help would be amazing

Comment: You need to create a new database.yml. I would run `rails new test` in another directory, and copy the database.yml from that app over to your broken one.

Comment: Unless you have production database credentials in your database.yml, you should keep that in your repo.

Comment: Okay..I can do that where will the db file be in the new test app?

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda a newb

Comment: It's in `config/database.yml`